# Names of bootable partitions aren't the same as the names in Disk Utility

Tags: startup, firmware

We use external FW/USB drives as portable diagnostic and installers and even though the partitions are named and have a custom icon, they show up as "Mac OS X" with a generic USB/FW icon when option booting.

How do I make the names and icons "stick" so they appear as I named them?

In System Preferences I've tried setting a partition as the startup disk and restarting when prompted; no change.

My current drive is formatted GUID and is broken into 9 partitions when viewed in Disk Utility. 8 are bootable and 1 is not. The retail partitions are the DVD installers or the Mac App Store Installers used to re-image new hard drives. The diagnostic partitions are a working OS with diagnostic utilities (DiskWarrior, Drive Genius, etc.) installed.

- 10.5.6 - Retail
- 10.6.3 - Retail
- 10.7.4 - Retail
- 10.8.1 - Retail
- 10.5.8 - Diagnostic
- 10.6.8 - Diagnostic
- 10.7.4 - Diagnostic
- 10.8.1 - Diagnostic
- Storage

[image: Option Boot]

Comment: Is the computer on which this shot was taken running 10.8.1?

Comment: I can't remember what machine this was booted on. I have multiple machines on which I can test.

Comment: Just post a screenshot of what it looks like on a machine with 10.8.1.

Comment: This image is drawn by the boot manager is firmware code and depends on the Mac and firmware level only as OS X hasn't been loaded yet.